# Autosys trigger same DataStage job multiple times with different inovacation IDs

Tags: datastage, autosys, file-watcher

Here is what I am trying to do, not sure if it is possible:

1. Autosys gets File1:10pm starts DataStage Job 1.1:10pm

Job1.1:10pm is still running

2. Autosys gets File1:20pm, it needs to start the same Job1 but run it as Job1.1:20pm, even though Job1.1:10pm is still running & not wait for it to finish, go ahead & run.

Can Autosys call the same DataStage job every time it gets a new file & run it with the new timestamp as the invocation id. Without waiting for the previous job to finish.

Thanks ya'll

Answer (score 0):

Yes - absolutely - this is possible. To enable different InvocationIds you have to check the  "multiple instance" property in the jobs properties. With this you allow multiple simultaneous runs of the job.

The invocationID can be a parameter as well when calling it from a sequence.

When your (multiple intance) job writes to a file make sure that each filename is unique to avoid side effects due to the multiple runs at the same time. This can be done by specifying DSJobInvocationId as part of the filename. Note that it is a parameter provided by DataStage which needs to be written exactly as shown with the upper and lower case letters. DataStage will the replace it with the content of your job invocationid at runtime.